# Google MLKIT Face Detector Size Unit

Tags: google-api, google-mlkit

What is the size unit in MLKIT Face detector (DP/PX/ETC) ?
for example in

```
Task<List<Face>> faceResult = faceDetector.process(inputImage);
Tasks.await(faceResult);

List<Face> faces = faceResult.getResult();

int width = faces.get(0).getBoundingBox().width();
```

what is the size unit of width?

Answer (score 0):

It is the pixel unit that matches the InputImage you passed in